# Python parser in field calculator malfunctioning

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

Shouldn't this return everything but the last word in the street name?

```
!Street_Name!.split(" ")[:-1]
```

Python parser is checked. Receiving nulls after calculation. If I try to slice[0], I get the first word. If I try to slice [-1] I get the last word. Why won't [:-1] return anything?

Comment: Unless there's a typo that seems like a bug. Out of curiosity, did you try `!Street_Name!.split(" ")[0:-1]`

Comment: @ KJYDavis Yes. I did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to join it back afterwards, otherwise you might be trying to calculate a field with a list:

```py
" ".join('101 1st Street'.split(" ")[:-1])
```

As @faith_dur noted though, this will fail when there are no spaces in the string. A better way to do this would be with [`rsplit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```py
for s in ['101 1st Street', '500 main street extension', 'NoSpacesHere']:
    print(s.rsplit(' ', 1)[0])
```

Which prints:

> 101 1st
>
> 500 main street
>
> NoSpacesHere

Comment: +1 Since the first code has an advantage over removing the extra spaces within the phrase and seems like `rsplit` is the elegant way of doing this instead of checking if the phrase is just one-word.

Comment: @Paul That's odd because I'm making this selection prior to the calculation  - Street_Name like ('% _') - so the records should all have at least one space and single final character. if there was a space at the end of a record it wouldn't be added to the selection. I there were no spaces then the select criteria (a space) between % and _ should exclude those records prior to the calculation attempt. I'll give your code a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is/are white space(s) at the end of your strings. Try `!Street_Name!.strip().split(" ")[:-1]`.

**EDIT**

I missed the colon in your slicing query. Please see below:

```
"xxxx yyyy".split(" ")[-1]   returns--> yyyy
"xxxx yyyy".split(" ")[:-1]  returns--> ['xxxx']
"xxxxyyyy".split(" ")[:-1]   returns--> []
```

Basically, `[:-1]` returns anything but the last slice (`"xxxx yyyy zzzz".split()[:-1]` returns `['xxxx', 'yyyy']`) and if you have only one word in your street address, naturally it returns an empty list. I think you are looking for

`!Street_Name!.strip().split(" ")[:-1] if len(!Street_Name!.strip().split(" "))>1 else !Street_Name!.strip()`

Comment: @faith_dur Thanks but still the same result.